# SSIS Connection String

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database

I have a local SQL DB and an Azure SQL DB. In my data flow I am trying to pass data from local (ole db source) to Azure (ole db destination).

I am unable to save the password for the connection string so I have parameterized the connection string of the data flow task but I seem unable to work out how to get the destination to use it?

I know this isn't best practice but I just want to prototype a few things. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: From my experience with Azure you need to use an ADO.net connection to comunicate with Azure thru SSIS

Comment: yeah, that was part of it. I also had to make my connection and parameter project level too... ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click project params and add your connection string as a parameter. Give it any name you want, select string then paste your Azure connection string that you have copied directly from you Azure portal connection string option.

This creates a project level conn string parameter.

Right click connection managers and create a new ADO.Net connection manager. This should be fairly straightforward.

Once completed, select this connection manager and add an expression to it from the property window:

In the Property Expression Editor: (1) Select a property called ConnectionString. (2) Select the elipsis beside expression. From the pop up open the project parameters in the left hand area and you will see the connection parameter you created earlier. Drag this into the expression text area. Evaluate the expression to check it works.

Click OK

You should now be able to use this as an Azure connection without getting any errors